# How to convert array keys into random string in php laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, string, laravel-7

I need to convert Array keys into a random string, how is it possible ?

This is how my array displays with the keys

[image]

I need to display as below by using `str_random(5)`

```
array:2 [▼
  bataj => 229
  akgrt => 228
]
```

Here's the codes to dump the array

```
 $files = $this->filesRepo->getByUuids($request->photos);

 $fileId = $files->pluck('id')->toArray();

 dd($fileId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$keys = array_map(function() {
    return str_random(5);
}, $fileId);

$fileId = array_combine($keys, array_values($fileId));

dd($fileId);
```